# How to deal with google privacy consent form (cookies)when trying to automate the google search function using selenium and java

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to automate the google search option to find the results of the search data.
Using the Selenium with java but getting stuck because of the google cookies.. the privacy consent form !
I tried switching to the form and clicking on the I Agree button but nothing works .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVr3d.png)

Comment: Can you please share your code so far?  - You will need to wait until the iframe isready, wait until the button is ready, complete the click, switch back the the main window, then wait for the google search bar to be ready or the cookie message to be gone. Happy to help but part of question is to show a minimal reproduceable example so we know what you've tried and provide bespoke help

Comment: driver =new ChromeDriver();
 driver.get("https://www.google.com");
 WebElement name=driver.findElement(By.className("fkimef I47yTd k8Lt0"));
 driver.switchTo().frame(name);
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"introAgreeButton\"]/div[2]")).click(); 
 }

Comment: That's not waiting until the frame is ready. What error you get? Is it nosuchelement?